# Custom classes and objects in Scala Toolbox typecheck

Tags: scala

I am trying to type check an arbitrary AST using Toolbox in Scala. Basically, I am building expressions using quasiquotes like

```
newTree = q"$oldTree + $x"
newTree = Typecheck(newTree)
```

where `$oldTree` is an AST with some type unknown to me. I need to fill in the fields like `newTree.tpe` based on the information already present in `oldTree` and `x`.

`Typecheck()` is defined as follows:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

import bitstream.types._

object Typecheck {

  def apply[A](treeStr: String): A = {
    val toolbox = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
    val tree = toolbox.parse(treeStr)
    toolbox.typecheck(tree).asInstanceOf[A]
  }

}
```

Currently I am trying to process the following:

```
Typecheck("types.this.Bit.bit2Int(d2_old)")
```

where `Bit.bit2Int()` is a method defined in an object `Bit` in the package `bitstream.types`. This is a package containing custom classes and objects. I currently get the error:

```
scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective typecheck has failed: types is not an enclosing class
```

My guess is that `bitstream.types` isn't in the context the mirror used by the Toolbox, but I don't know how to resolve this. I think [this Github issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/6393) is related, but I'm not sure how to interpret the discussion on the issue page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Typecheck("_root_.bitstream.types.Bit.bit2Int(d2_old)")
```

i.e. with package and without `this`.
(I have no idea what `d2_old` is and if you can put it there.)

Comment: Fantastic! This worked like a charm. As mentioned, `d2_old` is not valid by itself, but that's a separate issue specific to my program.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add `import` to tree;

```
val tree = toolbox.parse("""
  import bitstream.types._
  ${treeStr}
""")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried this, and it doesn't seem to have any affect.